# Peltier power limits

Tags: amperage, peltier

I have 12v peltier modules that I wish to run as a heater and ac unit but they have have a limit of like 27ma I have tried plugging then directly into a 2a car cigarette lighter adapter and they instantly got scalding hot on both sides so I figure it must be the amperage flow
How would I go about reducing the current enough to let this run continuously on 12v without risking damaging more cells in the process...

The intent right now is for heating a van but would hate to destroy the cooling functions of it...I do plan on mounting a cpu fan to this to dissipate heat as quickly as possible.I have successfully used these running off an 18650 cell directly with a cpu fan for about 1hr as a personal body temp control in the summer, only being moderately too cold for continuous direct contact with the skin to be comfortable but kept me feeling good in 100¤ weather when kept on my wrist.

Are these typically only run by some sort of smart switching mechinism in conjunction with a thermostat or what?

Comment: well, you'll probably first have to buy a new one.

Comment: I have two others already

Comment: ok, but seriously, 27mA is very little, and I don't know what they're supposed to deliver, but given an efficiency of much less than 10% for Peltier elements, I'd say you might be in for a disappointment.

Comment: What exactly are the specifications of the Peltier modules? Also how big (as in actual size) are they?

Comment: Apx 1 3/4" squared...

Comment: Post their datasheet. It's possible that "27mA" is the current they can generate (as a generator), while they can consume about 5A as a heater/cooler. Also, be aware that if you're heating something the size of a van, a conventional fluid/mechanical heatpump can move about 5x as much heat per watt of electrical or mechanical power.

Comment: I cant find the original source for those numbers module is tec1-12706

Comment: Well, google those numbers and you'll find its datasheet.

Comment: Im no tech expert just an average user and the way I interperate the data sheet I found this thing should be able to handle 6amps but was overheating with 2amp car cigarette adapter